# How to show alert box after successful data insertion in mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to show JavaScript alert  after successful data insertion in MySQL. How to do this? I have written this code but it shows JavaScript alert everytime I open this page and as soon as i click on OK of JavaScript alert it redirects me to finalmem.php, without the action of taking values from users!

```
$sql="INSERT INTO members VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$ybr', '$ach')";

if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

else
{

    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Successfully Registered"); location.href="finalmem.php"';
    echo '</script>';
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try [this](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=html%20alert%20box)

Comment: Why not use PDO - here's a good simple tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338

Comment: you have to put above code in if statement, e.g if you posting from form so `if(isset($_POST['submit']){ put above code here}` right now your code is like a door without lock, anyone can pass through.

Comment: It's unclear how your code above would work.  Is there anyplace you are attempting to submit this?

Comment: @Shehary i m using session also ... because i m validating data before form submission.<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['sname'] = $_POST["name"];
$_SESSION['sybr'] = $_POST["ybr"];
$_SESSION['semail'] = $_POST["email"];
$_SESSION['sach']= $_POST["ach"];
?> this part at starting then at the middle m doing data validation and then if all the inputs are correct then i m submitting the data . before the   $sql query above i have written $name = $_SESSION['sname'];
 $ybr = $_SESSION['sybr'];
 $email = $_SESSION['semail'];
 $ach = $_SESSION['sach'];

Comment: @nomistic yes these four variables will submit my data into a sql database i hav build on phpmyadmin.

Comment: @SankalpNigam please edit your original post to include that code.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use is set `isset($_POST['submit'])` to check whether user submits the form or not

```
    <?php

    include 'SQLIDB.php';   

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $ybr=$_POST['ybr'];
        $ach=$_POST['ach'];

    $sql="INSERT INTO members VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$ybr', '$ach')";

    if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    else
    {

        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Successfully Registered"); location.href="finalmem.php"';
        echo '</script>';
    }  

    }

?>

    <form action="" method="post">

        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="text" name="email">
        <input type="text" name="ybr">
        <input type="text" name="ach">

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but i m using session too because i m also validating the user inputs...

Answer (score 0):

You need to know two things, one of them it's to confirm if your data it's saved succefully.

For this you can play with

```
mysql_affected_rows()
```

and this function will return the number of rows affected by your query. If zero, it was not inserted. If >= 1, it was.

So:

```
if ( mysql_affected_rows() >= 1 ){ /* inserted! now do something... */ }
```

If you are using an auto-incrementing column for row ID, you can use mysql_insert_id() as well:

```
if ( mysql_insert_id() > 0 ) { /* inserted! now do something... */ }
```

Then you can work with jQuery UI for show a dialog like this:

```
[https://jqueryui.com/dialog/][1]
```

You need tot load the .css and .js files to run jQuery and inside your code put this:

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
```

And this in your view:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

Normally this it's super ugly to do for me, because the best way it's doing this by AJAX.

Comment: I have tried:                                                                                                               $sql="INSERT INTO members VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$ybr', '$ach')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

if (mysql_affected_rows() >= 1)
{
 
 echo '<script language="javascript">';
      echo 'alert("Successfully Registered");          location.href="finalmem.php"';
      echo '</script>';
}

Comment: um, the user is already using mysqli (a good thing) please do not suggest that they use deprecated code

Comment: @nomistic Oups, I don't saw this =) Try the same but with function in MySQLi http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: @MetElIdrissi Sir i used ' if (mysqli_affected_rows($con)>= 1) ' and its working too but whenever I refresh the page the alert pop up and as soon as i click on ok i m redirected to another page ,  page is not waiting for input in the fields...

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
<?php session_start();
//Include database detail here
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);
    $ybr = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["ybr"]);
    email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
    $ach = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["ach"]);

    //Do your data validation here

    $_SESSION['sname'] = $name;
    $_SESSION['sybr'] = $ybr;
    $_SESSION['semail'] = email;
    $_SESSION['sach']= $ach;

    $sql="INSERT INTO members VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$ybr', '$ach')";
    if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    } else {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Successfully Registered"); location.href="finalmem.php"';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Sir this is the first time i m using stackoverflow the code is long can u give me ur mail Id .. please

Comment: i have pasted. My username there is sankalpnigam.

Comment: Sir yes but when you put $flag="", form takes input and validates the data but .. the alert donot shows at all...